# console displaying quote character from gcc wongly

Tags: debian, console, gcc, unicode

After an upgrade to debian wheezy my text consoles displays questions marks where there should be quotes

Under X I see things correctly

```
window.cpp:1056:21: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
```

but the console shows

```
window.cpp:1056:21: error: base operand of ?->? is not a pointer
```

If I remove everything from that file except the quote and put xy around it (to spot it more easily), then emacs hexl-mode tells me it is this character

```
 00000000: 78e2 8098 790a                           x...y.
```

I understand 78 (x), 79(y) and 0a (LF) but I have trouble to believe that something as simple as a quote requires three unicode bytes.

I also tried

```
dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

and managed to produce more unreadable characters, but did not succeed to see the quotes correctly. I can type a single quote no problem and manpages and everything look okay, so I don't know whether gcc or the console is to blame.

Answer (score 5):

The fancy quote characters `‘’` are Unicode characters U+2018 and U+2019 (a single Unicode character each). Their UTF-8 encoding is a 3-byte sequence for each, e2 80 98 and e2 80 99 respectively. I have no idea why you have trouble believing that.

Evidently your environment indicates a UTF-8 locale. Run `locale` to display the relevant environment variables. It appears that your console is set up to display UTF-8 but the font does not include the characters `‘` and `’` so you see a `?` instead.

If you switch to a non-UTF-8 locale, gcc will use ASCII quotes instead (`` `->' ``).

Comment: Yes, my locale is set to UTF-8. You are also right about gcc not outputting fancy quotes when my locale does not specify UTF-8. So the remaining question is how to install a utf-8 console font. The console-data package is installed.

Comment: Meanwhile I installed the fonty-rg package which contains the LatCyrGr-16 font. Running setfont with this font and running unicode_start solves the problem. I still don't understand where I got off the beaten track and why this did not work out of the box.